# iTunesConnect IAP: check which subscriptions have been auto renewed

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

In my app I have auto renewable subscription as in-app-purchase. Is there a section in iTunesConnect (or elsewhere) where I can check which ones have been actually auto-renewed and which ones have been disabled?

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Let's say, for example, that a month ago a certain number of users purchased a monthly auto-renewing subscription. I want to know, today, how many subscriptions actually renewed and how many subscriptions have been disabled. Of course I can't simply check the number of today's transactions because there are also new subscriptions...

Comment: I am not sure but sales report should have this information. Just check this https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf

Comment: Reports actually have this information, thanks!